# Ignore wildcard Self-Sign Certificate warning only once for multiple domains in my local browser

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, self-signed

I have a wildcard self-signed certificate for two domains

`*.abc.com
*.xyz.com`

I'm access the servers https://one.abc.com and https://two.xyz.com via a third service https://three.abc.com and using the same self-signed certificate

I want to ignore the ssl warnings only once.

Note: I've broken down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions in the browser will be added only for the currently requested domain. If you want the self-signed certificate to be trusted for all domains contained in the certificate you have to explicitly add it to the trust store instead of only overriding the browser warnings.